# Extra RAM not showing up

Tags: ramdisk

I have an Asus A555-LF laptop with 4GB integrated RAM(1333 MHz DDR3) (non removable) and an extra RAM expansion slot. I installed another 4GB RAM to the laptop (1333MHz DDR3), but my BIOS, Windows 10 and Ubuntu doesn't detect it. I'm sure I installed it correctly in the computer (prongs are perfectly fitted and connectors lined up).

When I put this RAM on my older laptop, it is detected just fine.

Comment: A _mechanical_ fit does not imply a technical fit. Did you verify the detailed specs of the memory and compared it with the requirements for this motherboard? There is a multitude of timing and other specs.

Comment: Yes. Both my integrated RAM and the new RAM are 4GB 1333MHz DDR3 RAMs. What I'm trying to accomplish is 4GB + 4GB = 8GB of RAM. Would this work?

Comment: Yes, it should work. Another potential issue is that you might have a 32bit OS (yes, Windows 10 has a 32 bit version). They do not support more than 4GB.

Comment: Their website is useless, except that the machine should take 8GB of RAM:  DDR3 MHz SDRAM, OnBoard Memory 4 GB / 8 GB.

Comment: Supporting a maximum of 8 GB and support 8 GB modules are two entirely  different things.  There isn't enough information about the modules the author has to form any possible reason the system isn't detecting the additional module though.

Comment: My OS is 64-bit. Could it be possible that I need an 8GB RAM Stick instead of 4?